# Obtaining Upper level li text

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I currently have a list like so on my page

```
<li class="head">
    <b>Introduction</b>
    <ul>
        <li class="sub">somethingsomething</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

This list is being used with sortable, so the user can decide on the order, and I am passing this information to a grails controller for use in application logic. So, I am trying to read it in, and place the text contained in the "head" and "sub" classes in 2 different arrays. However, when I use a jquery selector to obtain the head elements, and obtain the text attribute of the element, it contains the inside list as well.

```
 $('#divname').find("ul > li.head").each(function()                              
      {                                                             
          var current = $(this);
          console.log(current.text());
      });
```

results in `Introductionsomethingsomething`

Is there any way to only obtain the 'Introduction' text from the list, and ignore the text in the nested `<ul>` and `<li.sub>`? Due to it being nested, I am unable to figure out how to use jQuery's :not() selector

Comment: _"So I currently have a table"_. That ain't no table amigo.

Comment: `$("#divname ul > li.head b").text()` comes to mind ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the `b` tag using jquery tagname selector.Like this:

```
 var current = $(this).find('b');
 console.log(current.text());
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ba5Q5/)**

Answer (score 0):

May be this is solution:

```
<script>
$('#divname').find("ul > li.head").each(function()                              
      {                                                             
          var current = $(this).find("b");
          console.log(current.text());
      });
</script>
```